# How to convert DateTime to shortdatetime in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a column in my datatable which is of DateTime Type. I only want the DatePart, hence when I use the ToShortDateTimeString it converts to short date but of string type. Hence when i reassign the string to the column of the datatable it again appends 12:00:00 to it. I cannot change the column type in my datatable. Is there any way to convert DateTime to ShortDateTime directly without converting to string?????

Comment: Is it correct you're looking for a data type that just holds the calendar date and not the clock time? That's how I'm reading the first revision.

Comment: ... cuz' rep is scarce with the influx of new users to this site and we're waiting like a ravenous pack of wolves to attack the issue ... I'm going to lunch now. If you could just wait until May 8, 2010 3:01:25pm EST to clarify that would be great and would sync with my schedule, otherwise without the time portion of the date I won't know when today to return and provide the right answer :)

Comment: yeah u r rite. I only want the date and not the time part. I am binding the datatable to a gridview. So it means the only option is to manipulate the data in rowdatabound event. I think Guffa's explanation is correct. Let me know if there is any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`.Date` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx), like this:

```
DateTime.Now.Date //just the date portion, like DateTime.Today would give
```

If you wanted to format on display, e.g. in a GridView, you can add the format to your column using [the `DataFormatString` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx), like this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ColumnName" DataFormatString="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" HtmlEncode="false" />
```

Comment: It embeds the time portion also - apparently question wants the time component gone?

Comment: @Abhishek - I'm confused by your question then, the time portion is a fundamental part of the `DateTime` type...you can't store that type without a time, all you can do is ignore it when displaying.

Answer (score 3):

No, that is not possible. Formatting it into a string doesn't help either.

The `datetime` type in the database always has both a date and time component. If you don't specify the time component it becomes `00:00:00` (or `12:00:00 AM` in 12 hour format). So, whatever you do to try to remove the time compontent, it will still have one.

Note that the `datetime` value in the database doesn't have a format. It's just a value representing a point in time.

So, you have to take care of the data whenever you read if from the database. If you just use the default settings to format the date value into a string, you will get both the date and time components, as they are always there. You have to specify the format that you want when converting the DateTime value to a string for display. For example:

```
string formatted = theDateTimeValue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: I am binding the datatable to a gridview. So it means the only option is to manipulate the data in rowdatabound event??

Comment: @Abhishek: You should be able to specify a format when binding the field to a grid column, something like what Nick added to his answer. Using a RowDataBound event would also work, that also gives you the ability to do what you like with the value before formatting it.

Answer (score 3):

If Dealing with DataGrids or GridViews, in date column format it using {0:d}, or simple D. If you are on web and using itemplate with table, tr and td and using binding template like <%# Eval()%> then you try the following

```
<span><%#string.Format("{0:d}",Eval("DataTableFieldName"))%></span>
```